# remove 'snap' from animation jQuery

Tags: jquery

Quick question, should be super easy for anyone keyed up on jQuery.
I have a page which uses scrollify. When I scroll down I have 3 animations that play, and are delayed.
I want to remove the 'snap' where the element snaps into place once the section is current.

You can view my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/pf98w5az/2/

I was using transparent like this

```
    $('.first').css("background-color", "transparent");
    $('.second').css("background-color", "transparent");
    $('.third').css("background-color", "transparent");
```

but that wasn't working out for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: im not using .animate function so doesn't apply to me sorry.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/twurjeam/ this is what I am trying to achieve - but I can't be using background-color: transparent

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

Use opacity.

That's all! :)